# Не могу войти через adminer в базу

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Помогите, кто знает. Вхожу через adminer в mariadb, через root все работает. Создаю базу, нового пользователя  с паролем, adminer не пускает. 
Выдает ошибку входа  [Warning] Access denied for user ... (using password: YES)
Через командную строку данным пользователем вхожу успешно.

Comment: И слава богу что не можете в базу войти, а то потом не выйдете еще. Нельзя в базу входить...

Comment: Вхожу в СУБД mariadb , но не в этом суть вопроса

Comment: Истина всегда кроется в деталях! Нельзя входить в СУБД, можно подключится к СУБД, авторизоваться в веб интерфейсе например.

Comment: Можно еще и синтаксических и орфографических ошибок найти, но думаю это не те детали. Я вхожу под рутом, все работает. Сейчас переключился на phpmyadmin, та же проблема. Если создаю пользователя для всех баз, то  подключается, если для одной конкретной базы, то авторизоваться в PMA не получается. Хотя этот же пользователь успешно авторизуется из командной строки

Comment: Вы пользователя то создали, а права ему хотя бы на подключение к базе выдали?

Comment: да, кончено, создал пользователя. Создавал и из командной строки и из PMA? Через командную строку же авторизуется успешно и базу свою видит

Comment: PMA установлен в контейнере docker. Это не может повлиять на проблемы со входом?

Comment: Немного разобрался, но не до конца. 
phpmyadmin  не дает войти под пользователем ‘user’@‘localhost’, пускает под пользователем  ‘user’@‘%’. , причем через командную строку mysql все отлично работает
В принципе можно и так работать, но не почему не пускает под localhost и какие последствия если работа под пользователем c хостом %  ?